# Selenium C# - How to wait with WebDriverWait using the element as parameter instead of a locator?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, visualstudio

I have a big problem, and I don't find the solution.

I have 2 classes: Components_BI.cs with this component:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='body-container']/div/div[1]/div/div/button[contains(text(), 'Paraméterek')]")]
public IWebElement login_Check { get; set; }
```

And Program.cs with this code:

```
WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
waiting.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((componentClass.login_Check)));
```

How to wait for this element with waiting.Until command?

Comment: This looks very relevant: [How to use Wait.Until with Selenium if I already have the element with FindsBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969229/how-to-use-wait-until-with-selenium-if-i-already-have-the-element-with-findsby).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to create your own `ExpectedConditions` class with methods accepting a `WebElement` as parameter, for example:

```
Wait.Until(MyConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
```

With the implementation in the `MyConditions` class, which works exactly like the existing `ExpectedConditions` methods.

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If element is null, stale or if it cannot be located
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Forget the *ExpectedConditions* and the *WebDriverWait*** -- **both don't work really well**.

1. If you have a *ImplicitWait*, the *WebDriverWait* is **completely ignored**. So you can not set the default timeout over ImplicitWait to 10 seconds and then create a WebDriverWait instance with 1 second only to check, if a element is present
2. *WebDriverWait* **ignores** the IgnoreExceptionTypes = *WebDriverTimeoutException*, so you need allways a try catch

With the following approach you have a simple and comfortable solution that works with a minimum of code:

```
using System.Linq;

#Decrease the timeout to 1 second
   Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

#FindElements get an array and Linq take the first or null
   var result = Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("h7")).FirstOrDefault();

#Increase the timeout to 10 second
   Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

**The result will be the desired IWebElement or Null**

> **Unfortunately** the getter to get the current value from *ImplicitWait* is **not implemented since 2016**. So you can only reset the value to a fixed value and not dynamically read it before.

Comment: "Both don't work really well" - based on what? Implicit waiting is discouraged, so we use only explicit waits and they work like a charm.

Comment: @FDM- then have fun with SPAs they use dynamic elements and explicit waits. We work with a base implicit wait of 10 seconds so that dynamicly loaded elements will be catched and we want a explicit wait, to check if a element is there with a smaller amount of time.
And when you read me first comment, you will also see, that the IgnoreException not really works, when you not can ignore the TimeoutException.

Comment: I'm testing nothing but SPAs. :) Of course you can't ignore a TimeoutException, that's the whole point of the Wait. You can't say to int.Parse(null) to not throw a NullReferenceException either.

Comment: Your response regarding the .Net versions of WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions is a bit harsh... but not unwarranted. See this blog post [Rantings of a Selenium Contributor](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2018/03/deprecating-parts-of-seleniums-net.html)